# Page break with dynamic content(printing)

Tags: jquery, python, css, html

My webpage gets generated dynamically so the height of my content is unknown. My question is, how do I go about splitting the page up for printing without the layout being cut in half or have my labels be on one page and the text boxes on the other. One option I was thinking was counting the number of section and splitting the page after every 2 sections or so (section is a big width: 100%, height: auto; block that contains a few input boxes and I have multiple sections)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

css

```
/* create `page-break-after` `odd` index elements , 
   i.e.g., first , third , fifth elements , etc. 
*/
section:odd {
  page-break-after : always;
}
```

See [page-break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) , [page-break-inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside)